# Flutter Web Mouse Region Widget Triggering

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am trying to get this result with Flutter;

[image]

I am having this behaviour;

[image]

Code;

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;

class OverlayAnimatedGridElement extends StatefulWidget {
  OverlayAnimatedGridElement(this.imagepath, this.postDetail, this.postTitle);
  final String imagepath;
  final String postTitle;
  final String postDetail;

  @override
  _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState createState() =>
      _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState();
}

class _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState extends State<OverlayAnimatedGridElement>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _opacityTween;
  bool isHovered = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _opacityTween = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc));

    super.initState();
  }

  hoverActivation(hoverState) {
    bool hoverState;
    isHovered = hoverState;
    if (isHovered = true) {
      _controller.forward();
    } else if (isHovered = false) {
      _controller.reset();
    }
    print("activated");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _opacityTween.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        print(_opacityTween.value);
      });
    });

    return MouseRegion(
      onHover: hoverActivation(true),
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 360, maxWidth: 640),
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Image(image: AssetImage("${widget.imagepath}")),
            Opacity(
              opacity: _opacityTween.value,
              child: Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(128, 128, 128, 0.5),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text("${widget.postDetail}"),
                        Text("${widget.postTitle}")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A standalone widget works okay but when I put it into gridview or pageview it automatically reads it mouse entered when I scroll into it.

I tried to use other widgets like Inkwell, Listener and others. No solution. Can someone guide me if there is better solution?

How Can I solve this?

edit:

[image: Multiple animation forwards]

Now having this problem. MouseRegion causes multiple controller.forwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am Created an Example ... please Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Todos',
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange),
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 3,
    children: List.generate(10, (index) {
      return OverlayAnimatedGridElement("https://picsum.photos/300/200");
        }
    ));
  }

}


class OverlayAnimatedGridElement extends StatefulWidget {
  OverlayAnimatedGridElement(this.imagepath);
  final String imagepath;
//  final String postTitle;
//  final String postDetail;

  @override
  _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState createState() =>
      _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState();
}

class _OverlayAnimatedGridElementState extends State<OverlayAnimatedGridElement>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isHovered = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  hoverActivation(hoverState) {
    setState(() {
      isHovered = hoverState;
    });
    print("activated" + hoverState.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network(widget.imagepath),
            MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (event){
                hoverActivation(true);
              },
              onExit: (event){
                hoverActivation(false);
              },
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(isHovered ? 0.5 : 0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please let me summarize and tell me if I am wrong. By putting a empty mouse region into stack you made sure it stays in stack, gets expanded to stacks size and does not get triggered by any bugs or mistakes from outside. This works as expected but right now I have performance issues. I have 2 more questions. Why we pass that event into the method? When I do not pass it it triggers it automatically when I do it waits. Is it default behaviour of MouseRegion? Second question is I am getting duplicate animation on this one. I guess this is for each mouse move "event"?

Comment: my brother ! sorry I am not understand your Questions Well ... please add an image or Explain more ... Because Both of us are not Native English speakers ! :)

Comment: I edited the main question so you can see current behaviour. Thank you. My main question was why we pass (event) to the anonymous function?

Comment: @ZayX If I Understated Correctly .. your Question Is About onExit and onEnter CallBacks... we Not Using The Event .. But `MouseRegion` only Accept a Function like That.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my second problem by just moving addListener method to initState. Previously it was inside widget itself which was causing adding listeners in every rebuild and causing multiple rebuilds for each listener, I guess.